# Distributed Transaction using WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, transactions, distributed-transactions

We have a requirement for a very specific scenario to implement distributed transaction in WCF service.  Here is the scenario:

1. Client makes a call to WCF Service
2. WCF Service updates Data in SQL Server
3. It makes a call to an external Java based web service which is responsible to update the same data in DB2 database

If anything fails in the above scenario, the entire transaction has to be rolled-back.  How we enable distributed transaction for the above scenario. Any inputs in this regard will be helpful. I understand Distributed transactions cause myriads of problems. However, I would like to know the potential solutions for the above issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a SQL Transaction. Use the transaction to insert into the SQL database. After calling commit I would call the java based web service from WCF and if it returns an exception when updating the DB2 database I would then rollback the SQL Transaction. The below link should help you.

[MSDN: SqlConnection.BeginTransaction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86773566(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You say you’d `COMMIT` after inserting into SQL Server, but then `ROLLBACK` that same transaction on-error afterwards… but you can’t rollback an already committed transaction.